# Scale table view cell height proportionally for all screens using autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have made a simple table view in .xib . i want to expand table view cells for all screen sizes(i.e iphone 6 , 6 plus and ipad ) .Currently i have hard coded the different heights for different screens like this :

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:       (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

   CGFloat cellHeight = 0;

    if (IS_IPHONE_6P) {

    // iphone 6P
   // cellHeight = 133;
    cellHeight = 175;


    }
    else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
    // on iphone 6
   // cellHeight =  120;
    cellHeight =  160;

    }

    else if (IS_IPHONE_5){
    //On iphone 5
   // cellHeight =  105;
    cellHeight =  145;

    }

    else if (IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS){
    //  on iphone 4
   // cellHeight =  50;
    cellHeight =  130;

    }
   else {
    //on ipad
   // cellHeight =  200;
    cellHeight =  280;

    }


   //  cellHeight = cellHeight *2;

     return  cellHeight;

     }
```

I there any better approach to this ?

Comment: CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) * ratio

Answer (score 2):

One of possible solutions are to get height of the screen and multiply by your ratio coefficient.

```
return CGRectGetHeight([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds) * ratio;
```

Comment: so i need to do this in heightForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: In this case what is `ratio`?

Comment: Tash, the percentage of screen. If you ratio = 1, your cell will be the same height as screen, ratio = 0.5 - cell height half of the screen

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to get the height of your `UITableView` and divide it with ratio you are looking for.

You can get the height of `UITableView` in your `viewDidLoad` or in your `viewDidAppear`

Comment: Those two methods are too early and the height you'd get is the storyboard height and not the final height on the device. Try using viewDidLayoutSubviews to get the actual height of the table view.